# Difference on two versions of spectrum of linear bounded operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, spectral-theory

I have seen two different kinds of definitions on spectrum, one is from [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectrum_(functional_analysis)#cite_note-1) and another one can also be found on many materials.

Suppose that $A$ is a bounded linear operator on a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$.

1st version:

the set-theoretic inverse is either unbounded or defined on a non-dense subset[Kreyszig, Erwin. Introductory Functional Analysis with Applications.]

2nd version:

(a)point spectrum(eigenvalue): $\sigma_p:=\{\lambda\in\sigma(A)| A-\lambda I \text{ is not one to one} \}$

(b)continuous spectrum: $\sigma_p:=\{\lambda\in\sigma(A)| A-\lambda I \text{ is one to one but not onto, and $ran(A-\lambda I)$ is dense in $\mathcal{H}$} \}$

(c)residual spectrum: $\sigma_p:=\{\lambda\in\sigma(A)| A-\lambda I \text{ is one to one but not onto, and $ran(A-\lambda I)$ is not dense in $\mathcal{H}$} \}$.

So, are they equivalent? If so, how shall I prove these two definitions are actually equivalent? Will the Close Graph Theorem be used?

Comment: Spectrum according to the first definition is the union of the three spectra in the second definition. This can be found in almost any book on FA.

Comment: Cf. the examples in this [book chapter](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~hunter/book/ch9.pdf).  Your Question is closely related to this previous one, [Difference between the spectrum and point spectrum of an operator.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1542943/difference-between-the-spectrum-and-point-spectrum-of-an-operator)